# How does whatsapp instantly receive a message?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a communication between my App and the server side. The app needs to receive messages from the server because it's remotely controlled. It works as a Background Service.

I'm currently getting the messages from the external MySQL by using HTTPPost, doing requisitions every 20 seconds, but it spends much battery.

I tried doing a Socket connection to a server (build in java): device connects to the server every 20 seconds and close the conn when it just receive the data, but it also spends much battery.

Is there a way of receiving these messages instantly as Whatsapp does?

Comment: Use a realtime database, like `Firebase`.

Comment: I think they use [XMPP](https://xmpp.org/software/servers.html)

Comment: I removed your answer from your question. You can self-answer your question if you want. But make it as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the app is open it's most likely a socket connection. This is usually how messengers work.

In the background though it's most probably using push notifications (Check FCM - Firebase Cloud Messaging). This source of info can be unreliable so making a service with requests once a minute or two could be cool

Comment: It works as a background service. Do you know about some tutorial of how to implement it?

Comment: unfortunately, no. But I can advice you to also look at a self-restarting background service. Because as soon as the phone will restart, the service will be gone as well. And you need to look for IntentService for background independant features

Answer (score 0):

In our messenger, we use long-live HttpsURLConnection as the main channel. The connection is hosted in Service and it is run in separate thread. In case of disconnect, we try to establish a new one. And we stop the service after our application is inactive for 2 minutes.

As the second channel, we use FCM.

This is what concerns messages. We also use WebRTC for multimedia data transfer. And we are going to use SIP calls to init voice- and video- call.

Comment: Could you please send me a code example of this long-live HttpURLConnection? It seems to be good.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do it - it's a commercial project and I can't share code (by my job contract). But I 've described an idea in general - it's enough to coding.